# Exec format error, Qt5 online installer on Lubuntu

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu, installation, xfce

I've looked everywhere and can't seem to find an answer so posting here.

Using a `64bit` Lubuntu VM,

Downloaded the Qt online installer from:
https://www.qt.io/download-open-source

The correct architecture installer downloaded

After `sudo chmod +x "qt-opensource-linux-x64....run"`

and typing in `./qt-opensource....`

I get:

> cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

So I don't really know where to take it from here, I didn't check the checksum because I couldn't find the checksum on Qt's download page but I download it twice in case the download was corrupted and got the same problem on both occasions.

Comment: Check AllDownloads->Info and compare the checksums. Probably your download did not finish correctly. Also you could just try using the offline installer.

Comment: The the downloads are not corrupted:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3hZTwavbHJ-R2xXWk5zdmdhbkE/view?usp=sharing